# Calling a method in if statement breaks down variables

Tags: c, if-statement, scope

I have a code like this

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<n ; i++)
{
    ....

    char* ref_error = "";
    if( isSeatAvailable(&tmp, movie_name, seat_number, &ref_error) == 0)
    {
        printf("available %s\n", seat_number);
    }
    else
    {
        logError(ref_error);
    }

    ....
}
```

If `isSeatAvailable` returns `0`, it works perfectly, but it returns `-1` and the program continues to else statement, the variables breaks down: like n becomes 4509408 etc.

The thing is,
If I re-write code like this and call `isSeatAvailable` method outside of if statement, it works perfect!

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<n ; i++)
{
    ....

    int res = isSeatAvailable(&tmp, movie_name, seat_number, &ref_error);
    if( res == 0)
    {
        printf("available %s\n", seat_number);
    }
    else
    {
        logError(ref_error);
    }

    ....
}
```

What might cause the problem here?

Here's the method I'm calling

```
int isSeatAvailable(hall** halls,char* movie_name,char* seat_no, int ticket_count, char** ref_error)
{

   ....
   sprintf(*ref_error,"Seat %s is not defined at %s.",seat_no,tmp->hall_name);
   ....   
}
```

Comment: What is the return value of the function isSeatAvailable?

Comment: it is either -1 or 0 (int)

Comment: You have some sort of memory corruption or stack overflow. Most likely caused by that function. Could also be that you have written code which invokes some form of undefined behavior.

Comment: Anyway, please post code that can be used to reproduce the error. The code for that function in particular. As it currently stands, nobody can answer the question.

Comment: Show at least the `isSeatAvailable` function. The problem is most likely in that function or maybe even in another function called by `isSeatAvailable`. Also using a debugger and stepping through your code might help here.

Comment: @Lundin see updated question. But I if a corruption occurs why re-writing it makes it work I wonder

Comment: @MichaelWalz see updated question

Comment: @jackjop if your `isSeatAvailable` messes up some memory it shouldn't , then all kind of strange behaviours may happen.

Comment: @jackjop calling `isSeatAvailable` recursively really looks fishy.

Comment: Recursive function probably means stack overflow. One of numerous reasons why you should always avoid recursion. But there might be several bugs here, those pointer-to-pointers look very fishy. How are the variables allocated in main?

Comment: There are no stackoverflow, because it actually doesn't call function again as ticket_count = 1

Comment: They are allocated normally with malloc

Comment: Terminology: C does not have "methods"; it has *functions*.

Comment: @jackjop show more code. Read about [mcve].

Comment: I updated my question as in `isSeatAvailable` function the problem code is `sprintf`

Comment: @MichaelWalz as I mentioned, the problem is caused by sprintf only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem *is* in the call to `sprintf`. The first parameter `ref_error` comes from:

```
char* ref_error = "";
```

And now `sprintf` tries to overwrite the constant `""` with the error message. Strange things will follow!

`sprintf` needs a real buffer (of sufficient size) to store the message into. Not just a pointer.